# Removing path segments with encoded values for nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url, proxypass

I have a `location` block like the following

```
location ^api/([^/]+)(/.+)$ {
     set $my_host $1;
     set $my_path $2;
     proxy_pass http://$myhost$my_path$is_args$args;
}
```

This works well for most normal cases for URIs such as `/api/foo/bar?1234`.

However when I introduce special URL encoded values, things go south. When the URI is `/api/foo/bar[%7B%7D]`, `$my_path` is decoded and is passed to `$my_host` as `/foo/bar[{}]`. This isn't a valid URL.

I've tried to work around the limitations of NGINX by using a conditional to match against `$request_uri` and `$uri`, but the results are either double encoded or unencoded.

```
location ~* ^api/([^/]+)(/.+)$ {
     set $my_host $1;
     if ( $request_uri ~* ^api/([^/]+)(/.+)$ ) {
          set $my_path $2;
     }
     proxy_pass http://$myhost$my_path$is_args$args;
}
```

In the above case `$my_path` is `/foo/bar[%257B%257D]`.

I have also attempted using `set_unescape_uri` from the set misc module for the second regex.

How can I get NGINX to remove the path components in the same format as the client provided them?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something was wrong with `set_unescape_uri` and the regex variable or something else. Using the single argument form of `set_unescape_uri` works.

```
location ~* ^api/([^/]+)(/.+)$ {
     set $my_host $1;
     if ( $request_uri ~* ^api/([^/]+)(/.+)$ ) {
          set $my_path $2;
          set_unescape_uri $my_path;
     }
     proxy_pass http://$myhost$my_path$is_args$args;
}
```